# pseudo-values for time-variant covariates

Tags: survival, time-varying-covariate, jackknife

I have the following time-varying survival data:

| ID | Start | Stop | Group | Z | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 0 | false |
| 2 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | false |
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 0 | 1 | true |
| 3 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | false |
| 3 | 3 | 12 | 1 | 1 | true |

I want to calculate the Jackknife pseudo-values by the following formula:

$$J_i(t)=n\hat{S}(t)-(n-1)\hat{S}^{-i}(t)$$

where $\hat{S}(t)$  is the approximately unbiased Kaplan-Meier (KM) estimate of the survival function at  based on a sample of size n, $\hat{S}^{-i}(t)$ is the survival function obtained from a leave-one-out sample by omitting the $$-ℎ subject from the sample.

Can you provide me an example to calculate the pseudo values for this data set?